# TDS classic 5.7 'Sync all projects with Sitecore' feature warning

Tags: helix, tds, serialization

I have upgraded TDS version from 5.5 to 5.7 for the tedious procedure of manual project sync. But when i do 'Sync all projects with Sitecore' I got the following warning

[image]

Is there any restriction of using the feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set up a [Global Config file as per the documentation](https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter4.html#global-config). You can then set the URL and path as follows:

```
<SitecoreWebUrl>http://your.url</SitecoreWebUrl>
<SitecoreDeployFolder>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\your.path</SitecoreDeployFolder>
```

You can then go through your TDS projects properties and make sure it is inheriting from the global config.

Also I'd advise upgrading to the latest version (TDS 5.8 at time of writing).